# thread_create: error error: ‘cpu’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, multithreading

I have this problem with C thread:
I have include cpu.h into main file, why this error persist??

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>                      
#include <sys/types.h>                      
#include <sys/stat.h>                       
#include <fcntl.h>                      
#include <unistd.h>                         
#include <string.h>                         
#include <stdlib.h>                         
#include <pthread.h>

#include "funzioni.h"
#include "ram.h" 
#include "cpu.h" 
#include "err.h"
......
......
rc = pthread_create (&threads[i] , NULL ,cpu, (void*)&parametri_thread_cpu[i] );
```

error: ‘cpu’ undeclared (first use in this function)

I include cpu.h into main.c

cpu.h

```
#ifndef FUNZIONI_H
#define FUNZIONI_H
void *cpu(void *thread_arg);
#endif
```

my Makefile

```
# Sources
SRCS= err.c funzioni.c cpu.c ram.c main.c
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=main.x

# Config
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -c
LIBS= -lpthread
LD=gcc

# Target

all: clean $(EXECUTABLE)


clean:
@echo Cleaning old files
@rm -f *.o *.x

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
@echo -------------Building $@
@ $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

err.o: err.c err.h
@echo -------------Building $@
@ $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<  

funzioni.o: funzioni.c funzioni.h 
@echo -------------Building $@
@ $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

cpu.o: cpu.c cpu.h funzioni.h err.h 
@echo -------------Building $@
@ $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

ram.o: ram.c ram.h funzioni.h err.h 
@echo -------------Building $@
@ $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

main.o: main.c ram.h cpu.h funzioni.h err.h  
@echo -------------Building $@
@ $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

this is my makefile for compiling code

Comment: That can't happen if you really included it. Post all the relevant code and how you compile them.

Comment: I have include in main.c #include "cpu.h".. for compiling I have a makefile

Comment: Show us what's in the makefile, show what you use to invoke it, and show the include - all of these things should be edited into your answer.

Comment: add makefile of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have copied your include guards from the other include file, "funzioni.h".

change it to `CPU_H` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the include-guard in cpu.h `#ifndef FUNZIONI_H` is already defined somewhere else.